LMST Model sensitivity - Beginners anti-luck
I have been experimenting with some very basic data for Alberta power markets, and trying to use a LMST model for time series data to try and predict prices. I do get "possible" results from my model, and it does seem to pick up some volatility that we can expect (just from my own market experience).
However, I am looking for a better understanding of maybe some of the pitfalls I am running into.
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.layers import Dropout
from keras.layers import Dense
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error,mean_squared_error
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import joblib

# Load the data
# Load the data

# Load the data
csv_file_path = 'Frankenstein.csv'  # Update with your actual file path
df = pd.read_csv(csv_file_path)

# Convert 'Date/Time' to datetime and extract components if present in your dataset
if 'Date/Time' in df.columns:
    df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date/Time'])
    df['Year'] = df['Date'].dt.year
    df['Month'] = df['Date'].dt.month
    df['Day'] = df['Date'].dt.day
    df['Hour'] = df['Date'].dt.hour
    df.drop(['Date/Time', 'Date'], axis=1, inplace=True)

# Assuming 'Price' is the target variable
features = df.drop(['Price'], axis=1)
target = df['Price']

# Normalize features and target
scaler_features = MinMaxScaler()
features_scaled = scaler_features.fit_transform(features)
scaler_target = MinMaxScaler()
target_scaled = scaler_target.fit_transform(target.values.reshape(-1, 1))

# Create sequences function
def create_sequences(features, target, time_steps=100):
    X, y = [], []
    for i in range(len(features) - time_steps):
        X.append(features[i:(i + time_steps)])
        y.append(target[i + time_steps])
    return np.array(X), np.array(y)

# Create sequences using the entire dataset
X, y = create_sequences(features_scaled, target_scaled.flatten())

# Model configuration
input_shape = (X.shape[1], X.shape[2])  # (time_steps, num_features)

# Define the LSTM model
model = Sequential([
    LSTM(units=100, return_sequences=True, input_shape=input_shape),
    Dropout(0.1),
    LSTM(units=100),
    Dropout(0.1),
    Dense(units=100, activation='elu'),
    Dense(1)  # Predicting a single value
])

# Compile the model
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')

# Train the model on the entire dataset
history = model.fit(X, y, epochs=150, batch_size=20, validation_split=0.1)

# Plot training & validation loss values
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
plt.plot(history.history['loss'], label='Train')
plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'], label='Validation')
plt.title('Model loss')
plt.ylabel('Loss')
plt.xlabel('Epoch')
plt.legend(loc='upper right')
plt.show()

# Save the LSTM model
model_save_path = 'trained_lstm_model.h5'
model.save(model_save_path)
print(f"Model saved to {model_save_path}")
joblib.dump(scaler_features, 'scaler_features.pkl')
joblib.dump(scaler_target, 'scaler_target.pkl')

Anyone out there that could give some advice to an absolute beginner? Mostly looking for a better understanding of how I should be setting this up. I have a dataset that is hourly, and is the past three years of historical generation and interchanges. I am looking for ways to make my model more reactive to changes in supply vs price.

You could try training the model to predict on a longer time-horizon, such the next 12 hours rather than just the next hour. This gives the model more context during learning. It's akin to changing the model into a multi-task or multi-forecast arrangement, rather than having it learn from just the next hour's forecast. It might also impart an averaging or stabilising effect on shorter-term trends, though I think it's worth trying. You could also modify the loss such that the model is penalised more for short-term errors, which will put more focus on the next hour's forecast.
The model's new output shape will be (batch size, forecast_length). At inference, even though the model will be outputting a prediction for the next 12 hours, you'd only read off the first value. Changes to the code would include something like this:
 ...
 #for each input sequence, the target is a "forecast_length" vector
 forecast_length = 14
 y.append(target[i + time_steps:i + timesteps + forecast_length])

At the moment the model is ingesting a sequence, and only rendering its prediction after stepping through all 100 frames (sequence-to-vector architecture). There can often be an improvement in changing to a sequence-to-sequence architecture, where you have a target forecast for each step in the input the sequence, rather than just a single target for the entire sequence. This can stabilise and speed up training as there are more error gradients and they don't have to flow through time as much. The input shape stays the same: (batch_size, sequence_length, input_size). The target shape changes to (batch_size, sequence_length, forecast_length) - there is a target for each point in the sequence.
For the current sequence size of 100 frames, it sounds like the model would consider about 4 days' worth of context when learning to forecast. There could be an improvement to be had by using a wider window. However, rather than simply increasing the sequence length (LSTMs might have a hard time), you can prepend a causal convolutional stage that learns to condense a wide receptive field down to a shorter sequence, ready for the subsequent LSTM stage.
You could also forego LSTMs altogether and go for a fully-convolutional approach, similar to the WaveNet architecture.
I think it's difficult to judge in advance what would work best with the data as it requires experimentation and tuning, which is why I've outlined a couple of strategies.

Thanks man, I really appreciate the input from more learned users like yourself. I will dig deeper into what've you said and try to implement it!
I will follow up if I get anything good!! Cheers
